# Firing destructor in non-static class that contains static field?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to test when a destructor is called in a class,When it is a simple class every thing goes as expected - when we leave instance's scope destructor is called.

But when we add a static field it does not happen.
Can anyone explain the concept behind this condition?

```
public class Test
{
    ~Test(){}
    private static string StaticField="";
    private float NonStaticField;    
}
```

And what would happen for other fields that are non-static and have values? Do they never get cleaned?

I tested calling destructor through Controller as you see below

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ts = new Test();
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I remove static field after leaving `Index` destructor is called.

Edit:calling destructor is a bit weird because it behaves different in static and non-static methods,if i create the instance inside an static method and leave the scope, destructor is called .

Comment: How did you test that destructor wasn't called?

Comment: Interesting. If you add call to GC.Collect(0) and hit Index page again, the object created in first hit will be collected and finalizer (destructor is C++) will be executed. It means your Test object wasn't propagated to Gen1 in any way. On the other hand, I don't understand why it was executed without static fields? You did't fill the whole Gen0 to trigger GC.

Comment: I think it's debugger who makes it behave this way.

Comment: it's somehow related to the stack and heap and  memory management concepts,But i don't know how classes that have static members are treated in .Net.

Comment: I don't see any errors. How did you check it? Everything is good - https://rextester.com/ZBLB5527

Comment: ~Test() is finalizer, not a destructor. The finalizer call is unpredictable. The behavior that you see could be the compiler optimization. The compiler sees a simple object that has finalizer and t just calls finalizer right away when object goes out of scope. Object with static field complicates things.

Comment: it depends on the scope we create instance that we expect to be destroyed.static or non-static method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think finally found out what is happening behind the scene,based on microsoft article,
Garbage collector think of the objects as one of the three Generations,
Generation 0,Generation 1,Generation 2 .
and it says implicitly that

> The heap is organized into generations so it can handle long-lived and
>   short-lived objects. Garbage collection primarily occurs with the
>   reclamation of short-lived objects that typically occupy only a small
>   part of the heap
>
> Generation 2. This generation contains long-lived objects. An example
>   of a long-lived object is an object in a server application that
>   contains static data that is live for the duration of the process.

and objects that fall into generation 2 category are not disposed immediately,
of course garbage collector behavior in web applications is different from windows applications.
to determine when garbage collector is performing it's job we should know about `latency`

> Latency refers to the time that the garbage collector intrudes in your
>   application

and default latency mode for web applications is `Interactive`:

> Enables garbage collection concurrency and reclaims objects while the
>   application is running. This is the default mode for garbage
>   collection on a workstation and is less intrusive than Batch. It
>   balances responsiveness with throughput. This mode is equivalent to
>   garbage collection on a workstation that is concurrent.

i am pretty sure that it's a vast topic that needs to be considered precisely,
you can use links below to read more about garbage collecting

[Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

[Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)

[Latency Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/latency)

Answer (score 6):

There is no predictable point when the destructor is called. The memory is managed by the [garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals):

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is
>   true:
>
> - The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low memory notification from the OS or low memory indicated by the
>     host.
> - The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
>     adjusted as the process runs.
> - The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs
>     continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and
>     testing.

So usually you are not interested when this happens, just that it happens. To see for myself I tried to repeat your experiment with a simple test program. The test function, that created the test class without a static field, was called multiple times. All created instances were only finalised and freed when the program finished.

If it is important and you want to control the moment when the instance is finalised, you should implement the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) interface and use a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: yes you are right,all of the information you have provided above is respected,But the thing is that i want to know what causes to not calling(at least immediately) destructor after leaving creation scope when the class contains a static field,While created instance has not any access to the static field.

Comment: i am not worried about calling destructor,In fact i just want to understand the concept behind this situation and i'm pretty sure it is somehow related to the heap and stack memory concepts and how they are managed.

Comment: My point is that basically the GC does what it does, when it does. In your example it freed the instance immediately without a static member. In my case it waited until the program ended anyway. In case of the static member the memory needs to remain, so the same value can be returned, when accessed later. To test, you could try to instantiate 2 objects with static member and see if one of them is destroyed immediately. I would not be surprised.